# Как пройтись циклом по массиву полученому из БД и поменять одно из полей

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Получаю С БД весь список.

```
#<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Item id: 1, name: "AAA", unit_price: 10000><#Item ....]
```

Далее мне нужно пройтиц циклом или итератором и значение unit_price поделить на 100, результат записать обратно и вывести в view.

Пробую так:

```
def index
    @items = Item.all
    @items.each{
        @items[unit_price] = @items[unit_price] /100
    }
end
```

В ответ получаю:

> undefined local variable or method `unit_price'

Смотрю в мануал хэшей

```
user = {name:"Vasya", last_name: "Petrov", age: 20}
user[:name] #=> "Vasya"
```

и пробую так:

```
def index
    @items = Item.all
    @items.each{
        @items[:unit_price] = @items[:unit_price] /100
    }
end
```

получаю ответ

> no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer

Наверное значение @items[:unit_price] он не считает integer хотя в бд оно так, ок ...

```
    def index
    @items = Item.all
    @items.each{
        @items[:unit_price] = @items[:unit_price].to_i /100
    }
end
```

получаю ответ

> no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer

Так @items.unit_price тоже пробовал, нет такого метода unit_price

как перебирать эти массивы и как обращаться к нужным полям?

Comment: вы хотите изменить значения в базе? или вы хотите просто вывести их на странице измененными?

Comment: Вывести на странице измененными

Comment: у вас цена в целых единицах 456, а вы хотите вывести их в виде 4.46?

Comment: @ Mikhail да, не хочу использовать decimal

Comment: У вас всё очень и очень плохо со знанием Ruby. В частности, вы не понимаете, как работает `each`, вы б [хотя бы сайт языка почитали](https://www.ruby-lang.org/ru/documentation/quickstart/4/).

Comment: @D-side Ну это то я в курсе, но мне надо сделать приложение за неделю и проходить весь базовый курс я не успеваю, по этому учусь на ходу.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам не надо менять значения в коллекции. Вам нужно при выводе использовать правильные `helper` и `partial`. Создаете `partial` (_item.html.erb) для вывода одного элемента и в нем используете примерно такой `helper`:

```
<%= number_to_currency(item.unit_price / 100.0) %>
```

А в основном **view**

```
<%= render @items %>
```

Лучшим вариантом будет использование gem [draper](https://github.com/drapergem/draper) или [keynote](https://github.com/rf-/keynote)

Answer (score 0):

Нужно проходиться по кожному элементу

```
def index
    @items = Item.all

    @items.each do |item|
        item[:unit_price] /= 100
        item.save # + сохранение в бд
    end
end
```

***Обновил ответ!!***

Comment: запись в базе менять не надо

Comment: @MikhailVaysman  ну так это пример. как вариант переписать массив не понравился

Comment: Мне на выхоте нужно получить такой же массив как и @items но поле unit_price: 10000 в итоге должно принять вид 100.00

Comment: @SergeiR ну так поделите на 100 и не сохраняйте. оно будет работать только для view